# Как в Yii2 изменить положение вывода ошибки?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть следующий код:

```
<div id="newsletter">
    <?php $form = \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::begin([
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'form-inline'
            ]
    ]) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->input('email')->label(false) ?>
        <?= \yii\bootstrap\Html::submitButton('Сообщить', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-lg']) ?>
    <?php $form->end() ?>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сообщение об ошибке выводится под полем для ввода email, но нужно, чтоб сообщение выводилось и под кнопкой.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Положение ошибки стилизуется через CSS.

Comment: Сделл так:
Ошибку не вывожу под полем с помощью шаблона  ['template' => "{label}\n{input}\n{hint}"], а в конце через <?= $form->errorSummary($model, ['header' => '', 'class' => 'has-error']); ?>